# Automatically and programmatically storing of a small piece of data on Ethereum

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible to have a dApp automatically and programmatically store a small piece of data on Ethereum, when needed (so upon request), without the need for manually connecting a wallet like MetaMask?

Does this kind of feature require a Smart Contract?

The goal would be to have an automated backend system store (dynamic) data on the Ethereum blockchain,  on the fly and whenever it needs to - using just one pre-approved/connect Ethereum wallet/address.. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible.

You have to build an app that runs continuously and sends a transaction to the blockchain upon some condition. A transaction that saves data on the blockchain interacts with a smart contract (aka dApp) already deployed on the blockchain, either by you or someone else.

Popular libraries to create such an app include web3js, web3py and etherjs.

The account sending the transaction must be unlocked before sending the transaction (the libraries provide functions to do so).